# Gerund or Adjective?

Tags: grammar, adjectives, gerunds

A man used his ***walking*** stick.
Is walking in this case a gerund or an adjective?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108434/discussion-on-question-by-skylr-song-gerund-or-adjective).

Answer (score 2):

> *A man used his walking-stick*

I'd say that "walking-stick" is a single word, a compound consisting of verb + noun, where the verbal element has the *ing* suffix (i.e. it has the gerund-participle form).

It has a purposive meaning ("stick for walking"), as do these similar examples: "frying-pan" ("pan for frying in"), "chewing-gum" ("gum for chewing"), "drinking-water" ("water for drinking").

Comment: This does nothing to actually answer the question—aside from changing the terminology, and also suggesting an unusual stylistic change that wasn't part of the question.

Comment: @IsabelArcher Yes, I would. I take "swimming-pool" as a single word, a compound noun ("pool for swimming in"), thus hyphenated. The same applies to the others. If they weren't written as a single word they would be syntactic constructions consisting of noun+modifier. But as compounds, they consist of two bases. Such compounds are mainly hyponymic, but there are a few lexicalised exceptions, such as "whipping-boy" and "scapegoat", though these don't have the clear purposive meaning of the others. Not all compounds are hyphenated, of course, cf. "greenhouse", "beehive", motorcycle" etc.

Comment: @JasonBassford It deals precisely with the question of the word class of "walking", adding by implication the interesting and relevant fact that since the word "walking-stick" is a compound, it thus does not consist of separate words in a syntactic construction. Compare "greenhouse" (compound) and "green house" (syntactic construction)

Comment: Is there an easily accessible source that suggests that these terms are compound nouns? I'm not disputing the viability of the concept -- just asking whether it has been espoused by any recognized sources.

Comment: @IsabelArcher Note that even if it were considered a compound noun, whether it should be open, hyphenated, or closed is a matter of style, not of grammar. You can find numerous examples of generally recognized compound nouns that take all three of those stylistic forms.

Comment: @IsabelArcher Yes, the award-winning and currently most authoritative grammar available, _The Cambridge Grammar of The English Language_ by Huddleston & Pullum.

Comment: And no, it's not a matter of style. There are certain tests that can be performed for compoundhood, but they are rather complex for discussion here.

Comment: Compounds are not 'open' as you put it. Such expressions are syntactic constructions (head+modifier or complement). Compounds are single words that happen in some instances to be hyphenated, cf. "ashtray" and "motorcycle" with "honey-bee" and "palm-tree". The hyphenation is relatively incidental to the contrast between compounds vs syntactic constructions.

Comment: @IsabelArcher There have been threads discussing the problems associated with the poser 'when is it correct to consider a two-orthographic-word string a compound?' [Is “missing person” considered a compound noun?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/212610/is-missing-person-considered-a-compound-noun) and [Compounds and Phrases {compound nouns vs free combinations, collocations}](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/227429/compounds-and-phrases-compound-nouns-vs-free-combinations-collocations).

Comment: Incidentally, note that compounds like "greenhouse", "sweetheart" and "cotton-plant" are pronounced with the main stress on the first component, while syntactic constructions like "green house", "sweet taste" and "cotton shirt"  have it on the second.

Answer (score 1):

Both gerunds and present participles can be used as adjectives. This is a gerund used as an adjective, not a present participle, because the stick itself is not doing the walking. The same goes for "swimming pool" or "reading glasses".

"He looked outside at the *falling* snow" is an example of a present participle used as an adjective. In this case, the snow is doing the falling.

See [Medium](https://medium.com/@engtuto1/can-gerunds-be-also-used-as-adjectives-89e5698411f3) for an explanation of the difference between a gerund used as an adjective and a present participle used as an adjective.

Comment: This is the correct answer, based on the conventional terminology and understanding of the terms.